# Как разбить строку, учитывая более одного разделителя между словами?

Tags: c++, строки, getline

```
while(getline(cin, s, ' '))
```

Это я использую для чтения строки с пробельным разделителем. А если слова в строке разделяются не только пробелом? По заданию учитываются запятые, табы, арифм. символы, скобки, конец строки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читаете строку, затем посредством `std::strtok` разбиваете на токены используя произвольное количество разделителей:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    ::std::string input{};
    ::std::getline(::std::cin, input);
    auto const & sz_delimeters{" ,."};
    auto psz_token{::std::strtok(input.data(), sz_delimeters)};
    while(psz_token)
    {
        ::std::cout << psz_token << ::std::endl;
        psz_token = ::std::strtok(nullptr, sz_delimeters);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MVtA65oA6ZGlBifE)

Comment: gcc 8 не может найти перегрузку strtok при использовании string в первом аргументе, чего нет при char*

Comment: Неправильно сказал, еще в редакторе ошибка присутствует

Comment: @xt1zer В моем примере первый аргумент как раз `char *`. Может у вас в настройках выставлен старый стандарт? `std::data` возвращающий `char *` был добавлен в С++17, до этого можно было обходиться указателем на первый элемент строки.

Comment: Мдям, 14 теперь старый... Спасибо за пример, все в порядке!

Comment: token в цикле это слово из строки? Я хочу впихнуть его в функцию, но вывод получается корявый

Comment: @xt1zer Да. В демо по ссылке видно как они разбиваются.

Answer (score -3):

Проще всего регулярные выражения использовать (перечислить нужные символы):

```
[^ ,\t+-\(\)\n]+
```

Comment: Как в моей задаче это использовать?

Comment: @xt1zer считываете в одну строку все данные из `cin`, потом используете `std::regex_search()` из заголовка `<regex>` с нужным регулярным выражением в параметрах

Comment: не понятно от слова совсем

Comment: @michael_best что непонятно?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277/Голоса-против-без-каких-либо-пояснений

Comment: куда следует вставить вашу строчку? это скорее комментарий, чем ответ

Comment: @michael_best вы предполагаете, что по одной строке кода из вопроса я должен угадать, куда в программе ТСа вставить строку с описанием ругулярного выражения из моего ответа, которая кодом не является?

Comment: значит это не ответ, почитайте спрвку

Comment: @michael_best любой ответ должен содержать код или что вы имеете в виду? не видел такого правила в справке

Comment: ответ - это развернутое объяснение, которое должно быть понятно не только вам. комментарий может быть почти любой - для этого они и созданы

Comment: @michael_best если ответ не понятен вам, то это не значит, что он понятен только мне

Comment: @michael_best кстати, предлагать мне написать комментарий к вопросу странно, так как сделать я этого физически не могу до 50 репутации

Comment: в этом и вся проблема. Задайте несколько умных вопрос, получите общее представление о сайте, и комментируйте от души!

Comment: уверен, одной строчкой нельзя объяснить регулярные выражение ни в Java, ни в плюсах

Comment: @michael_best мой ответ и не подразумевал объяснения синтаксиса или использовая регулярных выражений, для это есть специальные вопросы. Я дал идею алгоритма, чтобы ТС понял, что его задачи можно решить с помощью регулярных выражений

Comment: Поясню свой минус - вы дали регулярку, но не показали, ни как ей пользоваться, ни пояснили что именно она содержит и как работает, ни какие символы в ней куда вставить. То есть ваш ответ банально нельзя использовать. Да и вообще, использование регулярок для столь простой задачи не есть хорошо.